Springboot JPA postgres performance is slow
I have Springboot JPA integration with 2 databases. One is Oracle and the other is postgres 42.6.
I am fetching data from rest-api with 500 records in each request and saving it in postgres. Mostly the data is update and few are inserts.
Currently it is taking around 22 seconds to save the 500 records in postgres.
My application.properties:
spring.datasource.secondary.jndi-name=java:/datasources/IntegratorMasterdataDS
spring.datasource.secondary.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

spring.jpa.secondary.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect


spring.datasource.primary.jndi-name=java:/datasources/ItghPostgresXADS
spring.datasource.primary.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

I am doing configuration as below:
@Primary
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.tietoevry.absolutesoftware.itgh", entityManagerFactoryRef = "itghEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "itghTransactionManager")
public class ItghAutoConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.primary.jndi-name}")
    private String itghJndiDatasourceName;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource itghDataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup jndiDataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return jndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource(itghJndiDatasourceName);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager itghTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(itghEntityManager().getObject());
        
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean itghEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(itghDataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.tietoevry.absolutesoftware.itgh");
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        
        Map<String,Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 500);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", true);

        factoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);
        return factoryBean;
    }
}

for oracle database i am doing same way but without jpaProperties and making it secondary db.
@Repository
public interface ApplicationsRepository extends JpaRepository<Applications, String> {}

After add the 500 records in List i am calling
appRepository.saveAll(applications);
appRepository.flush();

Hibernate statistics: As per stats it shows that 70 batches were created but the sql are printed for each select query and each update/insert there is no batching. And it is taking same time if i am removing "batch_size" from jpaProperties.
Metrics {
    45644216 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    950436647 nanoseconds spent preparing 18711 JDBC statements;
    851450529369 nanoseconds spent executing 18641 JDBC statements;
    14912223124 nanoseconds spent executing 70 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    18845894086 nanoseconds spent executing 39 flushes (flushing a total of 388757 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}

Entity:
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "PD_Owner", name = "CIM_ABSOLUTE_APPLICATIONS_TAB")
public class Applications implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Device_Id")
    private String deviceAppId;

    @Column(name = "DeviceUid")
    private String deviceUid;

}

I am missing something which is not doing the batch insert/update properly.

What is your id generation strategy? What happens if you add hibernate.order_inserts=true and/or hibernate.batch_versioned_data=true? Also, with this many entities you may want to call entityManager.clear() after your flush to prevent memory issues.

Id generation is not there. Id’s are coming from rest-api. We are not doing ID generation

So, you are simply using the @Id annotation, no generation type? Can you show us your entities?

Updated question and added my entity. It has around 20 columns

I would try adding the two hibernate properties mentioned above and report back.

I have added below properties and tested. Tested with save and saveALL both.
Map<String,Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 50);
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.order_updates", true);
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.order_inserts", true);
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", true);
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data", true);

Please show the resulting hibernate statistics.

i have added the statistics above in question

Consider the following approaches :

Change the primary key generation strategy to GenerationType.SEQUENCE. If our entities use the GenerationType.IDENTITY identifier generator, Hibernate will silently disable batch inserts.
Set hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data to true. This allows Hibernate to batch inserts even with auto-generated IDs, if you are on versions 3.x and 4.x

References :
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/batch/Batching.html

Id generation is not there. Id’s are coming from rest-api.
